# Markov Chain limiting probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Give an example of a discrete Markov Chain $\{X_n\}_{n=0,1,\ldots}$ such that the limiting distribution $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n = i), i \in S$ all exists, and the sum of them is $1/2$. Can this be true if the $MC$ has a finite state space? Can this be true if the MC is irreducible?

My problem is, is this always true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n = i| X_0 = j) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n = i)$? If this is true, the limiting probability must sum up to $1$ right? I am very struggling now, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The probabilities should sum to one.

Comment: I guess you want to look up the concept of stationary distribution.

Comment: An easy example is a Markov chain on $S=\{\star,\varnothing\}\cup\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $p_{i,j}=\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i)$ satisfies $$p_{\star,\varnothing}=p_{\star,0}=\frac{1}{2},\qquad p_{\varnothing,\varnothing}=1,\qquad p_{k,k+1}=1\quad\forall k\in\mathbb{N}_0$$with the initial distribution $\mathbb{P}(X_0=\star)=1$. That is, if you are at the starting point $\star$, you toss a fair coin to decide whether you stuck at the absorbing point $\varnothing$ or take a free roller coaster starting at $0$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n=i)=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{\varnothing}(i).$$